# Input values from scanf but prints different values

Tags: c, matrix

I input the values from scanf but when i print them, all the columns have the last row's values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int N, M;
  int A[N][M];
  int T[N][M];
  int i,j;

  printf("Insert number of rows and columns: ");
  scanf("%d %d",&N,&M);

  printf("\nInsert the matrix\n");

  for(i=0; i<N; i++){
    for(j=0; j<M; j++){
      scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
    }
  }


  printf("\nInserted matrix:\n");
  for(i=0; i<N; i++){

    for(j=0; j<M; j++){
      printf("%d ",A[i][j]);

    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I've tried checking if it's a index problem and printing each element with its coordinate but that seems to be fine, the problem must be somewhere in the scanf.
Input:

```
Insert number of rows and columns: 3 3

Insert the matrix
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

output:

```
Inserted matrix:
7 8 9
7 8 9
7 8 9
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read up on [ask]. Also please create a [mcve]

Comment: Post a [mcve]. The posted code has no declaration nor definition of `A`, `N`, or `M`.  include with your reproduction the `#include` stack, `main`, and code that produces your problem.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question on stackoverflow, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Although you have added enough for people to figure out the problem, you have not provided an [mcve]. The source code in the question is missing a final `}`, and the full input is not shown—you showed an array but not the dimensions `3 3` that must also be in the input. To work with computers, you must develop habits of being **precise** and **complete**. The computer will not forgive errors or omissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn on compiler warnings. Any decent compiler will warn you that in:

```
int N, M;
int A[N][M];
```

`N` and `M` are not initialized. Because they are not initialized, you do not know what `int A[N][M];` will do. The array dimensions **must** be known when the declaration is reached.

You can move `int A[N][M];` and `int T[N][M];` to after the `scanf` that reads `N` and `M`.

Note that declaring arrays with variable lengths is not suitable for general code. It can be used for simple school assignments, but you should eventually progress to using `malloc` and other techniques. (Variable length arrays can also be used where the size is known to be within certain limits.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll look into gcc warnings and when i get to memory allocation I'll keep in mind your advice.
Could you tell me why this is bad practice compared to ```malloc```?

Comment: @thep1rate: Essentially all C implementations have a very limited amount of space available for objects with automatic storage duration (which includes objects that are defined inside functions but that are not `static` or thread-local), and using up that space with large arrays can cause the program to crash. Almost all C implementations use stack for automatic storage, and stack space is commonly quite limited, whereas `malloc` often has much more space available for use.

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. fails to check for errors when calling `scanf()`

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  int N, M;

  printf("Insert number of rows and columns: ");
  scanf("%d %d",&N,&M);

  int A[N][M];
  //int T[N][M];
  int i,j;

  printf("\nInsert the matrix\n");

  for(i=0; i<N; i++)
  {
    for(j=0; j<M; j++)
    {
      scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
    }
  }


  printf("\nInserted matrix:\n");
  for(i=0; i<N; i++)
  {
    for(j=0; j<M; j++)
    {
      printf("%d ",A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When run with the input:

```
3 3
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

The output is:

```
Insert number of rows and columns: 3 3

Insert the matrix
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Inserted matrix:
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9
```

The critical difference between the OPs posted code and this answer is the initialization of 'N' and 'M' before they are used in defining the size of the array: `A[N][M]`